# Syntax for creating internal table from existing database table?

Tags: abap, internal-tables, sap-data-dictionary

I'm new to ABAP. Started learning about internal tables. I was reading on the ways to create internal tables.

I came across the following syntax to create an internal table from an existing database table:

```
data: it_mara type table of mara.
```

I'm confused since mara is a table and if both l.h.s and r.h.s are of the same type then shouldn't it be just:

```
data: it_mara type mara.
```

What is the need to convert mara into a table when it is already a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MARA` is a transparent table which means that it functions at the same time as the structure type `MARA`. This is the way SAP works. :)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the reason. I attached a debugger to the program today to see the type of 'mara'. It said 'flat structure' which is weird since mara is a table. But maybe that's how the SAP ABAP runtime works. Seems like it considers a table to be a array of fields(structure) when referenced by its name in declarations and definitions. The name then internally points to the underlying database table. Weird!

Comment: @The-Droidster Maybe not necessarily weird but by all means confusing, especially for a rookie in the ABAP field! Enjoy learning it!

Comment: @The-Droidster It becomes even funnier. Try the following program and see of what type the variable `MARA` is. Look that it is defined with `TABLES` keyword. `REPORT ZZY. TABLES MARA. START-OF-SELECTION. SELECT * FROM MARA UP TO 10 ROWS. WRITE / MARA-MATNR. ENDSELECT.` It shows also how the name `MARA` is overloaded in this case.

Comment: Yes, I checked every occurrence of mara in the program today. It said  'flat structure'(even when the statement explicitly says 'TABLES' :D). Note: I can't actually run the code right now since I can only practice at my training institute(which has really bad trainers btw :D).

Answer (score 4):

Historical reasons (always a good guess...).

The original and nowadays obsolete way to declare a table (with a header line was `DATA it_mara TYPE mara OCCURS 10`. Without `OCCURS`, you didn't declare a table, so it became a structure. My guess would be that in order to maintain backwards compatibility, that wasn't changed when `TYPE TABLE OF` was introduced.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment on OCCURS. That gave me a hint. But I was more interested in why the runtime treats mara as a structure instead of a table in the first place. @Jaggers's answer seems to address that point.

Answer (score 1):

SAP **DDIC table** (transparent table, pooled table, cluster table) function as a **structure**.

Internal table is a list of **structure** (= **DDIC table**) values.

In your example of SAP DDIC table [**MARA**](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tabl/MARA.html) (General Material Data), we can define it as an internal table like

```
data: it_mara type STANDARD table of mara.
```

which creates an **STANDARD** internal table

```
data: it_mara type SORTED table of mara.
```

which creates an **SORTED** internal table